# Почему sum() в python предполагает, что в коллекции находятся именно числа?

Tags: python

Функция `sum()` в python3 имеет сигнатуру `sum(iterable, start=0)`. Какая причина того, что `start` изначально инициализируется нулем?

Почему бы не инициализировать `start` внутри самой функции первым объектом коллекции, если он присутствует, а иначе возвращать `None`?

Зачем это может быть полезно? Для начала, просто чтобы работа функции соответствовала ожиданиям: если у меня реализован для объекта метод `__add`, то я хочу его складывать, и я ожидаю, что функция суммы мне сложит все мои объекты в один, а не вылетит с ошибкой `TypeError`.

Comment: Вам бы лучше этот вопрос задать разработчикам Python ;)

Comment: А что это даст?

Comment: Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. The iterable’s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string. Наверное потому что сумма, это все таки число. А не что угодно реализующее __add и __radd

Comment: Наверное, так сделали именно для того, чтобы пустая коллекция не возвращала бы None?

Comment: @Эникейщик добавил в вопрос. Есть куча примеров, когда хочется использовать sum в месте, для которого он будто бы и создавался, а потом оказывается, что все-таки этот sum там не работает. Это все легко обходится небольшими костылями, но тогда зачем вообще нужна эта функция, занимающая очень удобное ключевое слово?

Comment: @Xander а чем вам мешает None? И если так угодно, то возвращайте, что хотите из пустой коллекции, но зачем ограничивать работу функции только числами, если язык полностью готов поддерживать более общий случай.

Comment: В любом случае, я не спорю, но просто хочу разобраться, существует ли сакральный смысл в этом ограничении, или разработчики языка просто почему-то сделали так, а не иначе, и теперь уже все привыкли, и никто ничего не хочет переделывать.

Comment: Совсем общий случай - общепризанно, это reduce. А сумма - это все таки числа. Когда будешь читать чужой код, о чем подумаешь, встретив слово sum? Какое будет удивление, что это на самом деле не операция с числами, а неведомыми объектами, для которых автор определил операцию сложения? По мнению разработчиков питона,есть более уместные альтернативы, об этом даже пишут в документации... Впрочем, критически мыслить и не со всем соглашаться, даже если это разработчики питона - это тоже отлично:)

Comment: Вдогонку хочется высказать, что я согласен с разработчиками языка - это не ограничения реализации языка, это ограничение мироздания, мы (люди) привыкли говорить о сумме только в контексте чисел и не хотим себя переделывать. Как много объектов, для которых операция сложения имеет привычный и до боли знакомый смысл? Сумма строк? Это конкатенация, значит и выглядеть это должно все по-другому. И это, по-моему, лишь один пример. А для зубодробильных математических приколов чистый python с его встроенными функциями без сторонних библиотек - ужасный выбор.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильный тип возвращаемого значения, как уже упоминалось в комментарии Xander - это, на мой взгляд, основная причина такого поведения `sum`. Возьмём простой пример:

```
def my_super_sum(arr1, arr2):
    return sum(arr) * 2 - sum(arr2)
```

В случае, если `sum` точно знает, что работает с числами, проблем тут не возникнет при любой наполненности коллекций `arr1` и `arr2`. Какие бы наборы чисел (в виде итератора) ни подать этой функции на вход, включая пустые коллекции (да, такое бывает, и это совершенно нормально) - всё будет работать, если функция `sum` от пустой коллекции возвращает `0`. Но не в случае, если она вернёт `None`. Ну либо тогда придётся менять и поведение питона при сложении чисел с `None`, считая его нулём. Короче, всё текущее поведение питона "поплывёт".

Проблема с вашим вариантом в том, что `Python` - язык без строгой типизации, поэтому пустой, например, список не имеет никакого типа. Нет элементов - нет типа. Нет типа - непонятно, что мы суммируем и как.

А ещё могут быть коллекции из смешанных типов. В питоновском списке могут быть произвольные элементы, любых типов, вперемешку. Поэтому ориентироваться именно на первый элемент в данном случае как-то очень не по питоновски.

Как правильно заметил mrEvgenX, если хотите ориентироваться на первый элемент последовательности - делайте это в явном виде, используя функцию `reduce`, которая именно под этот вариант и заточена.